# How to get the tag name of the next_element result for bsoup xml parsing?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I have an xml where I get the result of `s.next_element` as

`<string content="," height="10" hpos="235" style="bold" vpos="3129" width="4"></string>`

Now I want the tag of this element, which is `string`. How do I get it?

`s.next_element.tag` is not working.

Comment: Try `s.next_element.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.name`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name):

```
s.next_elemen.name
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""<string content="," height="10" hpos="235" style="bold" vpos="3129" width="4"></string>""", "html.parser")
print([x.name for x in soup]) # Output: ['string']
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Somehow, I never found this in any of the bsoup tutorials out there (or I'm probably going through the wrong ones) :D